# How can i get the first typed letter after empty space("") from UITextView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, character

I want to get the last word from the typed sentence in UITextView. For example "Apple i", from this example i need to get the last letter 'i' coming after " "(empty space). I want to do the functionality while the user typing in UITextView. How can i get the users first letter of the word after from empty space(" ")? Can anyone please help to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you like to seperate UITextView text in string by  space

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED Thanks for your spot response. Ya you are right. But, i want to get the first character after the empty space. Not to separate the string by space. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the string logic.

```
return [[textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
```

You can put this check in your `UITextViewDelegate` method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`. Don't forget to return `YES` here. You could also use `textViewDidChange:`.